# Bulk Edit EXIF Tags of a Large Number of Photos

Tags: exif, bulk

I have thousands of photos scattered across several subfolders (but all of them are under a single parent folder).
Most of those photos have values in their "Copyright" field, and that value differs from photo to photo.

Firstly, what I would like to do is to "cut" the value in the "Copyright" field, and "paste" it into the "Comments" field (a standard EXIF tag). I would like to this for all photos at once, and each photo has to keep its respective value (only now under a different category), of course.

Doing this photo by photo will take months - it's not an option.

Again, not all photos have a value in the "Copyright" field. Since manually selecting only the photo with value will also command a great deal of time, then I would like the process to simply ignore those photos without a value (or simply, "cut" an empty value and "paste" it - it makes no difference I believe).

Secondly, and after successfully doing the above, I would like to erase all EXIF information from all of those photos, BUT the "Comments" field.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Google "Exiftool". It will do it, when given the right parameters, now all you have to do is RTFM.

Comment: In Windows there is a option to remove that exit data from properties options in right click.

Answer (score 1):

[Exiftool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) will do what you want.

It's a platform-independent Perl library plus a command-line application for reading, writing and editing meta information in a wide variety of files.

Comment: I had assumed ExifTool would be the answer. I've heard of it and of how powerful it is, but it's CLI-based and has a learning curve, and I'm afraid of messing things up. Is there anything friendlier, with a GUI preferably? Thanks!

Comment: There are several GUIs for ExifTool, but I've never used any of them. Plus even if you use a GUI there is still a risk of messing up. Maybe trying ExifTool on  a copy of your files would be the way to go .